# Jquery fade in div as I scroll down

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, fade

I found this on another post and it works great except I need to reverse it so that when I scroll "down" it fades in the div.

```
var target = $('#bluOverlay');
var targetHeight = target.outerHeight();

$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var scrollPercent = (targetHeight - window.scrollY) / targetHeight;
    if(scrollPercent >= 0){
        target.css('opacity', scrollPercent);
    }
});
```

Here is the working fiddle from the other post http://jsfiddle.net/meEf4/

Comment: working fiddle from other post - http://jsfiddle.net/meEf4/

Comment: I don't get to see anything special in fiddle? Can you elaborate the problem bit? or what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao OP wants to show the div when scrolled down by increasing the opacity. `when I scroll "down" it fades the div "in".`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `opacity` of the `div` to zero initially and then when scrolled down increment the opacity gradually.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/meEf4/1604/)

```js
var target = $('div'),
  targetHeight = target.outerHeight();

$(document).scroll(function(e) {
  var scrollPercent = (targetHeight - window.scrollY) / targetHeight;

  if (scrollPercent >= 0) {
    target.css('opacity', 1 - scrollPercent);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px
}
div {
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```